# Have master page label display last edit date of child page being displayed

Tags: master-pages

i'm building an asp.net site with master pages. When visitors views a page, I'd like to show the date and time the child page was last updated. I'd also like to do this all at the master page level so no code for getting this information needs to be added to each child page.

Is this possible? what would be the best way to do it?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Page.Request.PhysicalPath` will give you the physical path of the page.

And the `FileInfo` class can be used to get its last update date.

There are caveats if you are redirecting using `Server.Execute` or `Server.Transfer`, in which case there are several alternative ways of doing this, including the one described in [the Remarks section of the MSDN documentation for HttpRequest.PhysicalPath](http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/1-4092/ms.help?method=page&id=P%3ASYSTEM.WEB.HTTPREQUEST.PHYSICALPATH&product=VS&productVersion=100&topicVersion=100&locale=EN-US&topicLocale=EN-US).

Comment: This is precisely the information i needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this is what I put in my `*_master.vb` code-behind files. And I use a base MainMaster.vb class with the `Public LastUpdate As DateTime`property.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
    Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(Page.Request.PhysicalPath)
    LastUpdate = fi.LastWriteTime
    label_lastUpdate.Text = String.Format("{0} à {1}", LastUpdate.ToLongDateString(), LastUpdate.ToLongTimeString())
End Sub
```